# Getting two scripts to work together

Tags: php, mysql, scripting

I'm trying to use the following scripts so that the result  of the first one determines the output of the second one.

```
<?
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','username','pass') or die("Database error");
mysql_select_db('dbname', $db);

$query = "SELECT pool FROM winners";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 

if ( $row['pool'] % 2 )
{ 
echo "<h4>Result 1</h4>";
echo "<br />";
}
else
{ 
echo "<h4>Result 2</h4>";
echo "<br />";
}
?>


<?php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost','username','pass') or die("Database error");
mysql_select_db('dbnamesameasother', $db);


$query2 = "SELECT * FROM comments";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))

if ( $row2['commentid'] % 2 ==0 )
{ 
echo $row2['name'];
echo "<br />";
}
else
{
echo $row2['name'];
}
?>
```

So basically if the first script chooses Result 1 I only want to echo the names which associate with that result. The names are associated by commentid where an odd commentid would be result 2 and an even commentid would be result 1. Is there any way to do this without using a union statement?

Comment: Why can't you just use a single script? At the end it is compiled as a single script.

Comment: sounds more like a database/SQL question than a PHP/scripting one

Comment: I am querying 2 different tables within the same database. Is it possible to write it as one script and do that? Sorry I just started writing php like a week ago.

Comment: @user1206214 Of course it is :)

Comment: yes it is. basically that's why `relational` databases are named like that. post some table structure so we might guide you

Comment: Table 'comments' has the columns commentid, tutorialid, name, date: Table 'winners' has the columns pool, pool2, pool3, pool4, pool5, pool6, pool7. Table 'comments' has multiple rows that are updated through user input. Table 'winners' has only 1 row with numbers that are randomly generated daily.

Comment: any `relationship` among those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It recommend that you to create  a function and then call it.something like this :

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','username','pass') or die("Database error");
mysql_select_db('dbname', $db);

$query = "SELECT pool FROM winners";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 

if ( $row['pool'] % 2 )
{ 
echo "<h4>Result 1</h4>";
$names = get_names(1);
  foreach ($names as $name) {
   echo $name . "<br/>";
  }
}
else
{ 
echo "<h4>Result 2</h4>";
$names = get_names(0);
  foreach ($names as $name) {
   echo $name . "<br/>";
  }
}

Function get_names($pool_result) 
{
  $name_array = array();
  $db = mysql_connect('localhost','username','pass') or die("Database error");
  mysql_select_db('dbnamesameasother', $db);

  $query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commentid % 2 = $pool_result"; 
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    array_push($name_array , $row['name']);
  }
  return $name_array;
}
?>

}
```

Comment: I like where you are going with this idea, but it's giving me the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' on line 117 and I don't see what the problem is with your code. Line 117 is the } one line after return $name_array;

Comment: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` should be: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){`

Comment: Thanks blake, that fixed the parse error. However The only output I'm getting is the result from "result1' or "result2" which is working fine but the part where it outputs the names still isn't working.

Comment: @user1206214 Updated , but im not sure about sql statement that is used in get_names im searching for it , and you can do this also

Comment: I found another malfunction in the script. When 'Result 2' is called up I get the error Fatal error: Call to undefined function push_array()

Comment: Well that fixed the fatal error but I'm still not getting any names outputted

Comment: Ok , im @ work and here i haven't any sql server to test the query i do this for you as soon as when i come back to home just relax and keep searching about using mod operator in mysql.

Comment: changing to $query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commentid % 2 = $pool_result"; fixed it

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help, I tried to upvote your comment but it wont let me cause I don't have enough rep here